# Need delay in loop [ Android]

Tags: android, delay, sleep, countdowntimer

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class PlantNow extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

Button cd;
TextView tvcd;

public class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {

    public MyCountDownTimer(long startTime, long interval) {
            super(startTime, interval);             
        }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        tvcd.setTextSize(30);
       tvcd.setText("BOOOOOOOOM");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         tvcd.setText("" + millisUntilFinished/1000);
    }
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //FullScreen Start
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    //FullScreen End
    setContentView(R.layout.plantnow);
    tvcd=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvcd);
    cd=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b11);
    cd.setOnClickListener(this);
}
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(arg0.getId()){
    case R.id.b11:
        tvcd.setTextSize(20);
        tvcd.setText("Message Here");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        MyCountDownTimer countDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(30000, 1000);
        break;
    }

}
```

}
This is the current code, i am having, I added the new MyCountdowntimer class as well, but its giving me warning that my post is mostly code, oh god why, I am kinda new to stackflow and its giving me lot of problems xD

Comment: try running an empty for loop like---
for(int k=1000;k>0;k--);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {
     public MyCountDownTimer(long startTime, long interval) {
        super(startTime, interval);
     }

     @Override
     public void onFinish() {
        text.setText("Time's up!");
     }

     @Override
     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
          text.setText("" + millisUntilFinished/1000);
     }
}
```

and start it as

```
MyCountDownTimer countDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(30000, 1000);
```

It will last 30seconds. The onTick will be invoked for 29 times every second. The onFinish is the last to be called

Comment: But I have to initialize my TextView as tvcd=(TextView)findViewById(r.id.tvid) , but I cant, I am getting error as findViewById method not found.

Comment: can you explain what's your problem

Comment: Nvm, done by making an object of Activity class and calling it via it.

Comment: Nope, the app is still crashing :| , and it crashes when I call MyCountdowntimer class.

Comment: how does it crash? What execption did you get?

Comment: post the content of the logcatg

Comment: Null Pointer exception is coming when I initialize my textView public class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {
 Activity act=new Activity();
 TextView tvcd=(TextView)act.findViewById(R.id.tvcd);
  .........//Rest same

Comment: then the issue is not the CountDownTimer. Post the onCreate

Comment: This is my Onclick Method: public void onClick(View arg0) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  switch(arg0.getId()){
  case R.id.b11:
   tvcd.setTextSize(20);
   tvcd.setText("Message Here");
   try {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
   MyCountDownTimer countDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(30000, 1000);
   break;
  }
  
 }  , as soon as I call mycountdowntimer, it goes BOOM

Comment: put MyCountDownTimer inside your Activity, as innerclas, and declare the TextView a Class member. also you must remove "Activity act=new Activity(); TextView tvcd=(TextView)act.findViewById(R.id.tvcd); " from the MyCountDownTimer

Comment: its not crashing but the MycountdownTimer is not updating textview,neither any message is coming after 30 secs.

Comment: Update your question and post the whole class

Comment: Done sir. I am new to android so I will be frequently here :P

Comment: can you see this message  tvcd.setText("Message Here"); ?

Comment: you missed countDownTimer.start();

Comment: inside onClick after  MyCountDownTimer countDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(30000, 1000);